# Change height of input textfield JSQMessageController

Tags: swift, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have the following problem with `JSQMessageViewController` in an iPhone X-range deployment.

[image]

The home-bar overlays the input field and the rounded bottom-corners cut-off part of the field. How can I adjust the height so this doesn't happen?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I m having same problem. I m trying to solve it by adding the extension for JSQMessagesInputToolbar

```
extension JSQMessagesInputToolbar {
override open func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *), let window = self.window {
        let anchor = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
           bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingBelow: anchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]